# Calling notifyDataSetChanged on a ListAdapter

Tags: android, listadapter

I have a `ListAdapter` as shown below:

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(DeleteMenu.this,             
                                  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, 
                                  classes));
```

I am trying to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on it within an `onListItemClick()` function. I've tried a few different ways and looked at similar questions here on StackOverFlow but I still can't figure it out.

Can someone please help?

Edit: I should be more clear, I'm not getting an error, I simply don't know what to call the function `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on. Do I have to assign my `ListAdapter` to a variable and call it like `var.notifyDataSetChanged()`?

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the actual problem? what do you want to do?

Comment: what's the error? Post the code in question. Also post your logcat output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should call `notifyDataSetChanged` on Adapter.

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thanks but could you elaborate on this a little bit?

Comment: You call notifydatasetchanged on your adapter. You can't do that in your example cause you didn't give it a name to refer to it later. Does that make sense?

Comment: There is no need to assign the adapter to a local variable. You are able to retrieve the adapter anywhere in a ListActivity/ListFragment by calling getListAdapter().

Answer (score 8):

You can call the method notifyAdapterChanged() by getting a reference to the Adapter. You can either keep a local reference (like user1411084s answer), or retrieve it by calling:

```
getListAdapter()
```

Important to notice is that the interface ListAdapter doesn't provide the method `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so you should cast it to the type of the adapter you assigned earlier.

The result will look like this (able to call anywhere in your ListActivity/ListFragment:

```
((ArrayAdapter) getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: getListAdapter() if your class extends http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#getListAdapter()

Answer (score 3):

```
((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

See more info in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4198569/3994630