# notifyDataSetChange not working from custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter, notifydatasetchanged

When I repopulate my `ListView`, I call a specific method from my `Adapter`.

**Problem**:

When I call `updateReceiptsList` from my `Adapter`, the data is refreshed, but my `ListView` doesn't reflect the change.

**Question**:

Why doesn't my `ListView` show the new data when I call `notifyDataSetChanged`?

**Adapter**:

```
public class ReceiptListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<Receipt> receiptlist;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DateHelpers dateH;

    public ReceiptListAdapter(Activity activity, Context mcontext, List<Receipt> rl) {
        context = mcontext;
        receiptlist = rl;
        Collections.reverse(receiptlist);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        dateH = new DateHelpers();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            int size = receiptlist.size();
            return size;
        } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void updateReceiptsList(List<Receipt> newlist) {
        receiptlist = newlist;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Receipt getItem(int i) {
        return receiptlist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return receiptlist.get(i).getReceiptId() ;
    }

    private String getPuntenString(Receipt r) {
        if(r.getPoints().equals("1")) {
            return "1 punt";
        }
        return r.getPoints()+" punten";
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;

        final Receipt receipt = receiptlist.get(position);
        ReceiptViewHolder receiptviewholder;
        Typeface tf_hn = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helveticaneue.ttf");        
        Typeface tf_hn_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helveticaneuebd.ttf");

        if (vi == null) { //convertview==null
            receiptviewholder = new ReceiptViewHolder();
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_listitem_receipt, null);
            vi.setOnClickListener(null);
            vi.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            vi.setLongClickable(false);
            receiptviewholder.shop = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_shop);
            receiptviewholder.date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_date);
            receiptviewholder.price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_price);
            receiptviewholder.points = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_points);
            receiptviewholder.shop.setTypeface(tf_hn_bold);
            receiptviewholder.price.setTypeface(tf_hn_bold);
            vi.setTag(receiptviewholder);
        }else{//convertview is not null
            receiptviewholder = (ReceiptViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

        receiptviewholder.shop.setText(receipt.getShop());
        receiptviewholder.date.setText(dateH.timestampToDateString(Long.parseLong(receipt.getPurchaseDate())));
        receiptviewholder.price.setText("€ "+receipt.getPrice());
        receiptviewholder.points.setText(getPuntenString(receipt));

        vi.setClickable(false);
        return vi;
    }

    public static class ReceiptViewHolder {
        public TextView shop;
        public TextView date;
        public TextView price;
        public TextView points;
    }

    public Object getFilter() {
        // XXX Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

--EDIT:

**found Workaround**

Just to have some functional code i do now:

```
listview.setAdapter( new ReceiptListAdapter(activity,mcontext, -new dataset-);
```

Works, but not how it is supposed to work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4198569/2382964 ,Hi Jasper please refer this link ... this will help you .

Comment: try other methods like notifyItemInserted, notifyItemRemoved,etc..

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Change your method from

```
public void updateReceiptsList(List<Receipt> newlist) {
    receiptlist = newlist;
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

To

```
public void updateReceiptsList(List<Receipt> newlist) {
    receiptlist.clear();
    receiptlist.addAll(newlist);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

So you keep the same object as your DataSet in your Adapter.

Comment: consider having a parent object like `ReceiptListObject` instead of a `List` of objects, what can you do then to solve this problem?

Comment: @prom85 can ArrayAdapters even bind to Objects other than Lists or Arrays? I did not know.

Comment: it's about a `BaseAdapter` and this adapter does not know to which data it is binded... so if I have an custom object and use custom functions of this object (like `custObject.getCount()` and `custObject.getChildAt(int i)` for example), and I want to exchange this object, `notifyDataSetChanged` is not working... anyway, I think this problem does never occur with an `ArrayAdapter`

Comment: btw, are you talking about the `ArrayAdapter` only? There your answer makes sense... I would have no idea why exchanging the list object should make a problem in a `BaseAdapter`... But I can't get a BaseAdapter to work properly, without resetting the adapter instead of calling `notifyDataSetChanged`...×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes×Comments may only be edited for 5 minutes

Comment: Can you maybe explain why the first method doesn't work and the second works with a BaseAdapter?

Comment: @tolgap this question was directed to you :) The first solution worked for me for some time, but then it stopped working, and I had to change the code like in the second method. Now it's working fine.

Comment: @Tooroop I can't imagine the first solution working, because all you do is change the reference of the `receiptlist` variable. The `BaseAdapter` has no knowledge of this, so `notifyDataSetChanged()` would not change anything. You should work on your initial reference `List` and remove/add items to that `List`.

Comment: Somehow It is not working with a static arraylist of mine. I have 2 adapters In first This works like a charm. But in 2nd Same Adapter it gives a force close says ArrayOutOfIndex and notifydatasetchanged not working

Comment: @Tooroop I had used the second way by clearing and add new items. But changing it to first way worked for me. Very strange.

Comment: comments like Thanks or +1 are not allowed but on some answers I really like to give a thank :)

Comment: Hello everyone i use these methods you mention but does not work for me. Could you please anyone check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827414/android-update-listview-through-baseadapter-in-postexecute-not-working

Comment: I think in Kotlin at least you will need to use a MutableList to get clear() and addAll().

Answer (score 27):

I have the same problem, and i realize that. When we create adapter and set it to listview, listview will point to object somewhere in memory which adapter hold, data in this object will show in listview.

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
listview.setadapter(adapter);
```

if we create an object for adapter with another data again and notifydatasetchanged():

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(anotherdata);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this will do not affect to data in listview because the list is pointing to different object, this object does not know anything about new object in adapter, and notifyDataSetChanged() affect nothing.
So we should change data in object and avoid to create a new object again for adapter

Comment: you are recreating the adapter object, it is not efficient

Comment: @Alezis I think that's exactly what Nhan meant.

Comment: Hello everyone i use these methods you mention but does not work for me. Could you please anyone check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827414/android-update-listview-through-baseadapter-in-postexecute-not-working

Answer (score 22):

As I have already explained the reasons behind this issue and also how to handle it in a different answer thread [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479071/1084174). Still i am sharing the solution summary here.

One of the main reasons `notifyDataSetChanged()` won't work for you - is,

**Your adapter loses reference to your list**.

When creating and adding a new list to the `Adapter`. Always follow these guidelines:

1. Initialise the `arrayList` while declaring it globally.
2. Add the List to the adapter directly with out checking for null and empty
   values . Set the adapter to the list directly (don't check for any
   condition). Adapter guarantees you that wherever you make
   changes to the data of the `arrayList` it will take care of it, but never loose the
   reference.
3. Always modify the data in the arrayList itself (if your data is completely new
   than you can call `adapter.clear()` and `arrayList.clear()` before
   actually adding data to the list) but don't set the adapter i.e If
   the new data is populated in the `arrayList` than just
   `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! The tip at #2 helped.

Comment: Hello everyone i use these methods you mention but does not work for me. Could you please anyone check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827414/android-update-listview-through-baseadapter-in-postexecute-not-working

Answer (score 4):

Maybe try to refresh your ListView:

`receiptsListView.invalidate()`.

EDIT: Another thought came into my mind. Just for the record, try to disable list view cache:

```html
<ListView
    ...
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    ... />
```

Comment: Weird, my last idea is to reassign adapter to list view  after data changed. But I suppose you already tried this too.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem using `ListAdapter`

I let Android Studio implement methods for me and this is what I got:

```
public class CustomAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {

    }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that these methods do not call `super` implementations so `notifyDataSetChange` is never called.

Either remove these overrides manually or add super calls and it should work again.

```
@Override
public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    super.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
}

@Override
public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
    super.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
}
```

Comment: Hello everyone i use these methods you mention but does not work for me. Could you please anyone check my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66827414/android-update-listview-through-baseadapter-in-postexecute-not-working

Answer (score 2):

If `adapter` is set to `AutoCompleteTextView` then `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't work.

Need this to update adapter:

```
myAutoCompleteAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myList);

myAutoComplete.setAdapter(myAutoCompleteAdapter);
```

Refer: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/10/autocompletetextview-with-dynamic.html

Comment: Thanks. This worked. But I didn't get any answer why `notifyDataSetChanged()` does not work with `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Answer (score 2):

If by any chance you landed on this thread and wondering why `adapter.invaidate()` or `adapter.clear()` methods are not present in your case then maybe because you might be using `RecyclerView.Adapter` instead of `BaseAdapter` which is used by the asker of this question. If clearing the `list` or `arraylist` not resolving your problem then it may happen that you are making *two or more instances* of the `adapter` for ex.:

*MainActivity*

```java
...

adapter = new CustomAdapter(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

...
```

and
*SomeFragment*

```java
...

adapter = new CustomAdapter(newList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

...
```

If in the second case you are expecting a change in the list of inflated views in recycler view then it is not gonna happen as in the second time a new instance of the `adapter` is created which is not attached to the recycler view. Setting `notifyDataSetChanged` in the second adapter is not gonna change the content of recycer view. For that make a new instance of the recycler view in *SomeFragment* and attach it to the new instance of the adapter.

*SomeFragment*

```java
...

recyclerView = new RecyclerView();
adapter = new CustomAdapter();
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

...
```

Although, I don't recommend making multiple instances of the same adapter and recycler view.

Answer (score 1):

```
class StudentAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    ArrayList<LichHocDTO> studentList;

    private void capNhatDuLieu(ArrayList<LichHocDTO> list){
        this.studentList.clear();
        this.studentList.addAll(list);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

You can try. It work for me

Answer (score 1):

In my case I simply forget to add in my fragment `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)`

Answer (score 0):

**Add this code**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { public void run() {
               adapter = new CustomAdapter(anotherdata);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a very noob mistake that I was setting the adapter of RecyclerView before initialzing the adapter itself like this.

```
    // Assuume oneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter is declared already 
    recyclerView.setAdapter(oneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter);        
    oneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter = new OneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter();
```

Switching the lines fixed my issue.

```
    oneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter = new OneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter();
    recyclerView.setAdapter(oneOffJobTasksListRVAdapter);
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem
but I just finished it!!

you should change to

```java
public class ReceiptListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public List<Receipt> receiptlist;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private DateHelpers dateH;
    private List<ReceiptViewHolder> receiptviewlist;

    public ReceiptListAdapter(Activity activity, Context mcontext, List<Receipt> rl) {
        context = mcontext;
        receiptlist = rl;
        receiptviewlist = new ArrayList<>();
        receiptviewlist.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < receiptlist.size(); i++){
          ReceiptViewHolder receiptviewholder = new ReceiptViewHolder();
          receiptviewlist.add(receiptviewholder);
        }
        Collections.reverse(receiptlist);
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        dateH = new DateHelpers();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            int size = receiptlist.size();
            return size;
        } catch(NullPointerException ex) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public void updateReceiptsList(List<Receipt> newlist) {
        receiptlist = newlist;
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public Receipt getItem(int i) {
        return receiptlist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return receiptlist.get(i).getReceiptId() ;
    }

    private String getPuntenString(Receipt r) {
        if(r.getPoints().equals("1")) {
            return "1 punt";
        }
        return r.getPoints()+" punten";
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;

        final Receipt receipt = receiptlist.get(position);
        ReceiptViewHolder receiptviewholder;
        Typeface tf_hn = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helveticaneue.ttf");        
        Typeface tf_hn_bold = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "helveticaneuebd.ttf");

        if (vi == null) { //convertview==null
            ReceiptViewHolder receiptviewholder = receiptviewlist.get(position);
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_listitem_receipt, null);
            vi.setOnClickListener(null);
            vi.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            vi.setLongClickable(false);
            receiptviewholder.shop = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_shop);
            receiptviewholder.date = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_date);
            receiptviewholder.price = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_price);
            receiptviewholder.points = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tv_listitemreceipt_points);
            receiptviewholder.shop.setTypeface(tf_hn_bold);
            receiptviewholder.price.setTypeface(tf_hn_bold);
            vi.setTag(receiptviewholder);
        }else{//convertview is not null
            receiptviewholder = (ReceiptViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

        receiptviewholder.shop.setText(receipt.getShop());
        receiptviewholder.date.setText(dateH.timestampToDateString(Long.parseLong(receipt.getPurchaseDate())));
        receiptviewholder.price.setText("€ "+receipt.getPrice());
        receiptviewholder.points.setText(getPuntenString(receipt));

        vi.setClickable(false);
        return vi;
    }

    public static class ReceiptViewHolder {
        public TextView shop;
        public TextView date;
        public TextView price;
        public TextView points;
    }

    public Object getFilter() {
        // XXX Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

My case was different but it might be the same case for others

for those who still couldn't find a solution and tried everything above, if you're using the adapter inside fragment then the reason it's not working `fragment could be recreating so the adapter is recreating everytime the fragment recreate`

you should verify if the adapter and objects list are null before initializing

```js
if(adapter == null){
  adapter = new CustomListAdapter(...);
}
...

if(objects == null){
  objects = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a custom adapter you have to add

```
@Override
public void notifyDataSetChanged() {
    super.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to your custom adapter methods, then you only need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you change your data, like replace, remove or add a new item

```
ArrayList <String> items;
int position=1;
items.set(position,"Changed Item");
items.remove(position);
items.add("New item");
notifyDataSetChanged();
```