# How to populate JSON data into ListView using ArrayList

Tags: java, android, json, listview, arraylist

I have successfully parsed JSON data into ListView using ArrayList, but unable to populate List based on `City` name.

Like I am allowing user to select City and then l am trying to populate results into ListView using new ArrayList, but not getting any data into ListView.

```
public class TitleListActivity extends Activity {

  ....

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_title);

    ......
    new JSONAsyncTask().execute("http://murl.com/json/citywise.json");  

    try {
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
            Toast.makeText(TitleListActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

            // not getting data city wise
            cityWiseSearch();
        }
        else
        {
            // getting all data
            adapter = new TitleListAdapter(TitleListActivity.this, R.layout.row, allArrayList);             
            listview.setAdapter(adapter); 
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    ....
}

class JSONAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            ....

                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("cities");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    destination = new TitleList();                      
                    destination.setTitle(object.getString("address"));                      
                    allArrayList.add(destination);

                ......

        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        ....
    }
}

public void cityWiseSearch() {              

    for (int i = 0; i <allArrayList.size(); i++) {
        destination = (TitleList) allArrayList.get(i);

        String strStatuss = allArrayList.get(i).getCity();

        if (strStatuss.equalsIgnoreCase(value)){                
            cityArrayList.add(destination);         
        }                      
    }              

    adapter = new TitleListAdapter(TitleListActivity.this, R.layout.row, cityArrayList);        
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

   }
 }
```

Comment: if this post deserves downvotes then do, but also tell me the reason of downvoting ...

Comment: Guys please dont downvote without telling the reason, as a developer you stuck in problems hence we all use stackoverflow.

Comment: first check if this "http://murl.com/json/citywise.json" returning a proper response, then check what data are you getting before binding to the arraylist. Print on log. also before using  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); empty the ArrayList. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422120/notifydatasetchange-not-working-from-custom-adapter, and then post your output/error log.

Comment: thank you @AmitabhSarkar i will be back soon... thanks found the issue

Comment: please mention the solution also, so that other can benifit from it.

Comment: @AmitabhSarkar i just missed destination.setCity(object.getString("city")); due to this was not getting the city name :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your `setAdapter code inside onPostExecute` and you must need to fetch `city` name as you are fetching `title` to compare city name in **cityWiseSearch()** method

```
destination.setCity(object.getString("city"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ListView` is empty beceause of you update the `ArrayList` but you have to send `allArrayList` to the adapter before calling

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: but i am getting all data, not getting when trying to fetch based on city name only

Comment: Ok. So you should try to add
Log.v("City", strStatuss +" - "+value);
just after this line : 
String strStatuss = allArrayList.get(i).getCity();