# Android Parse - Pininbackground not working

Tags: android, parse-platform, local-datastore

I am implementing group chat using Parse in my Android Application . and the scene is , when sender sends any message to group , i am pinning this message with a label in parse local data store at sender side. and i also put auto refreshing method, which retrieving data from parse local data store every second. but the problem is when i am calling pinInBackground method , data is not being populating in ListView using adapter. but when i call saveInBackground and pinInBackground method  together then it is being populating.

I check that size of data is also increasing in localdatastore. but not reflecting in ListView.

I am using following method for retrieving data from localdatastore -

```
    private ArrayList<ParseObject> mMessages;
        private MyCustomAdapter1 mAdapter;
        private ListView lvChat;
         private boolean mFirstLoad;

//in onCreate() method      
        mMessages = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
        lvChat.setTranscriptMode(1);
        mFirstLoad = true;
        mAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter1(getActivity(), mMessages);
        lvChat.setAdapter(mAdapter);

private void receiveChatMessages() {
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("ChatMessages");
    query.orderByAscending("createdAt");
    query.fromPin("myLable");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mMessages.clear();
                mMessages.addAll(list);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // update adapter
                // Scroll to the bottom of the list on initial load
                if (mFirstLoad) {
                    lvChat.setSelection(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                    mFirstLoad = false;
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("message", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Question - What would be the reason that saveInBackground method is being reflecing data but pinInBackground is not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you enabled LocalDataStore ? Paste code of your Custom Application class

Comment: I edit my question please check.

Comment: paste manifest as well plz

Comment: how you know that value is not stored in local data store .. because configuration looks okay

Comment: Thanks. Sorry that was my mistake , i put some wrong lable name while querying. Now Could you please answer my edited question?

Comment: mMessages is what ? can you paste code of class from where you called above class as well

Comment: Please Check my edited Question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422120/notifydatasetchange-not-working-from-custom-adapter can you try this i think there is problem with referesh you are doing

Comment: Thanks @virendrao . +1 for you. Its working for me. But facing one more issue that is i want to query in local data store on basis of "createdAt" column of parse. but there is no way to insert "createdAt " in localdatastore. so is there any way to apply "orderByAscending" query , so that i can see all recent message in ascending order?

Comment: you want ascending or descending ? what all values you have .. or you can store message using current time as new column

Comment: yes. All are of String type. Ok. Thanks