# How to update the data of an adapter correctly?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Is there a difference between:

```
@Override void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Items> rows) {  
   this.dataset.clear();  
   this.dataset.addAll(rows);  
   this.dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
}
```

and

```
@Override void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Items> rows) {  
   this.dataset.clear();  
   this.dataset = rows;  
   this.dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  
}
```

Both seem to work correctly but most of the examples I have seen about this use the first pattern.
Is the second wrong?

Comment: On a cursory look, it seems first one assumption is you have already declared the variable as this.dataset = new ArrayList<Items> so that it doesn't throw the null pointer somewhere prior to this call and that is standard practice. Second I think doesn't require the new call.

Comment: semantically the two operations are different.

Comment: @sumandas if `this.dataset` is `null` in the second example, `this.dataset.clear()` would throw a NPE.

Comment: @Ed : Ohh missed that line, was just focusing on the difference between the two snippets. you are absolutely right of that lead to an issue.

Comment: #2: i know if the array has never held elements, it will work fine first pass, but a 2nd pass through, it won't update with new rows.

Comment: @TWL wow, very interesting. I was skeptical when I read this, but I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422120/notifydatasetchange-not-working-from-custom-adapter is exactly what you are describing.

Comment: I know, I don't have a real explanation behind why it is, just that it works as I and many others have bumped into this problem before.

Comment: @TWL:Can you please elaborate? I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: it has something to do with `=` is unable to connect to the same object, so the old `this.dataset` never gets the new rows. thats why #1 is used, most commonly in updating listviews (#2 will bug out).

Answer (score 0):

i found answer on Doc Oracle,
+ addAll(Collection c): Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator
+ this.dataset = rows: just tell data in dataset will remove and fill all data from "rows" into dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `addAll()` and the variable assignment is that `addAll()` according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)):

> Appends all of the elements in the specified collection to the end of this list, in the order that they are returned by the specified collection's Iterator.

This means should a `List` be non-null, any objects added using the `addAll()` method would be appended to the end.

The variable assignment on the other hand would *replace* the current List stored in `this.dataset` with the List `rows`. This would therefore not append anything to the previous List.

**However**, as the method uses `this.dataset.clear()` which according to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()):

> Removes all of the elements from this list. The list will be empty after this call returns.

The functionality of the two methods *is the same*, as the list is empty before being appended to or overwritten.

---

Please note, to avoid a `NullPointerException` it would probably be best to add some sort of if-statement to check if `this.dataset` is null before calling `this.dataset.clear();`

In the second example, the `this.dataset.clear()` is also redundant, as the variable is overwritten immediately afterwards.

Comment: So the fact that we instantiate the adapter with a reference and change the reference has no impact on the notify?

Comment: Can you rephrase that @Jim? Not sure I am following you. If you are saying that your adapter is not refreshing,  I think what you need to be doing is changing the dataAdapter's _inner_ dataset, it looks like you aren't doing that at present.

Comment: I am asking if the fact that we replace the reference instead of adding/modifying items from the list that the adapter had a reference can have any subtle problems