# android update ListView through Baseadapter in postexecute not working

Tags: android, android-listview

I use this code to update the listview of my project but i get duplicates by using the listview.invalidateViews(); method. Also i tried the notifyDataSetChanged method by calling it from the customadapter of mine that extends baseadapter but it does not seem to work properly. I need to update using the postexecute method after downloading the data from online source. Please check below my code.

The HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

    Bitmap mIcon12;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ArrayList< String> arrayList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> aList;
    private int scrollState;
    private int offset = 0;
    private Button btnLoadMore;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private boolean loadingMore = false;
    TextView textinput2;
    ImageView lv1;
    View root;
    View root1;
    ProgressBar pb;
    private int scrollpos;
    private ListView lv;
    public ArrayList<SubjectData> arrayList1;
    CustomAdapter adapter1;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        homeViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        root1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home);
       lv = root.findViewById(R.id.homelistview);
       lv1=root1.findViewById(R.id.flagimageview);
        arrayList1 = new ArrayList<SubjectData>();
       lv.setClickable(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Object o = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
            
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "myPosss "+position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });


        MainActivity main1 = (MainActivity)getActivity();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
      
            adapter1 = new CustomAdapter(getContext(), arrayList1);
            System.out.println("to lv den ine null edopoooooooooooo");
         
        } else {
        
        }





        pb = new ProgressBar(getContext());
        lv.addFooterView(pb);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

  
        if (!flag) {
            new loadMoreListView().execute();
            flag = true;
            System.out.println("to flag1 ine: "+ flag);
        }
        lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount,
                                 int totalItemCount) {
                scrollpos = totalItemCount;
                int lastPos = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
             
                if ((lastPos == totalItemCount) && (!loadingMore)) {
                    if (totalItemCount < 250) {
                        System.out.println("to flag4 ine " + flag);
                       new loadMoreListView().execute();
                    } else {
                        lv.removeFooterView(pb);
                    }

                }
            }
        });


        homeViewModel.getText().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }


    private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask< Void, Void, String> {


        protected String doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            loadingMore = true;
            String result = null;
                 String url = "https://api.androidhive.info/json/imdb_top_250.php?offset=" + offset;
            try {
               URL mUrl = new URL(url);
               
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();


                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000); //set timeout to 5 seconds
                urlConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                String str = "";
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(str);
                }
                result = buffer.toString();

       
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error " + e);
            
            }

            return result;
        }


        /*
         * An InputStream that skips the exact number of bytes provided, unless it reaches EOF.
         */
        public class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {

            public FlushedInputStream(InputStream inputStream) {
                super(inputStream);
            }
            @Override
            public long skip(long n) throws IOException {
                long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;
                while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
                    long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);
                    if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                        int b = read();
                        if (b < 0) {
                            break;  // we reached EOF
                        } else {
                            bytesSkipped = 1; // we read one byte
                        }
                    }
                    totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
                }
                return totalBytesSkipped;
            }
        }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View vi=convertView;


            return vi;
        }




        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(result);
                  
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        

                       arrayList1.add(new SubjectData(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("title"),"link", "image"));

                    }

                    loadingMore = false;


                    System.out.println("to flag2 ine: "+ flag);
                    lv.invalidateViews();

                   // adapter1.updater(arrayList1);

                   

                    offset+=20;

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                if (pb==null)
                {
                    System.out.println("ine null to pb ");
                }
                else if (lv==null) { 
                pb.setVisibility(pb.GONE);

                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Please check your internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                pb=null;
                }
                else
                {
                    lv.removeFooterView(pb);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And this is the customadapter that extends the baseadapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
   public ArrayList<SubjectData> arrayList;

    Context context;
    Thread t;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubjectData> arrayList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }


    public void updater(ArrayList<SubjectData> updatedlist)
    {
       this.arrayList.clear();
        this.arrayList.addAll(updatedlist);

      this.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }


    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }


    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SubjectData subjectData = arrayList.get(position);
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null);
            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AppCompatActivity activity= (AppCompatActivity)context;
                    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
                  image.setImageResource(R.drawable.notificationstoreicon);
            
                    final ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(context);
                
                    String[] coupons = {"horse", "cow", "camel", "sheep", "goat"};
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                            new AlertDialog.Builder(context).
                                    setTitle("Details").
                                    setView(pb).
                                    setMessage("please wait...")
                   .
                                    setPositiveButton("Go", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                       
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                            // dialog.dismiss();
                                            if (t.isAlive())
                                            {
                                             

                                            }
                                            else
                                                {

                                            }
                                            
                                        }
                                    });
                    AlertDialog dialog1=builder.create();

                            dialog1.show();
                   t= new Thread()
                    { private volatile boolean running = true;
                        public void run() {
                            System.out.println("blah");
                        
                            while (running) {
                                try {
                                    // thread to sleep for 1000 milliseconds
                                    Thread.sleep(4000);
                                    running=false;
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    System.out.println(e);
                                }
                               
                            }
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    dialog1.setMessage("more details");
                                    pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Picasso.get()
                                            .load(subjectData.Image)
                                            .into(image);
                                   dialog1.setContentView(image);
                              
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        public void stopThread() {
                            running = false;
                            interrupt();
                        }

                        public void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable){
                            final Handler UIHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                            UIHandler.post(runnable);
                        }


                    };
            t.start();



                }
            });
        
            TextView tittle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            ImageView imag = convertView.findViewById(R.id.flagimageview);
            tittle.setText(subjectData.SubjectName);
            Picasso.get()
                    .load(subjectData.Image)
                    .into(imag);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {

        if(getCount() > 0){
            return arrayList.size();
        }else{
            return 1;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Fragment home xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:text="Please check your internet connection!"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/homelistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/helloimageview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="productimage"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help appreciated. I searched in other people posts but no luck! I have been searching for hours actually!

Can anyone help me? Cant find solution!

Comment: Please remove the Imports and add only a [mcve] . Whole bulk of code is hard to understand . Also you do not need `invalidateViews` u only need to call `adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged()` . Debug your code see if data is getting parsed and getting added in array List properly.

Comment: When i call notifyDataSetChanged() it keeps triggering Oncreate from HomeFragment and i do not understand why is this happening! I am removing the imports.

Comment: This is driving me crazy really! I mean this is the worst coding experience i have ever had with android! this is worst than writing code in non UI interface. programming in 90s was much easier! Just to populate a listview i am trying for days now! Unbelievable situation!

Comment: You are using lots of outdated API like AsyncTask, ListView Even Thread .. You said `when i call notifyDataSetChanged() it keeps triggering Oncreate from HomeFragment` . That should not happen its probably means Your app getting crashed . Check the Logs and add the error stacktrace with question.

Comment: No i have found what is the issue and keeps triggering. Its the clear() function of the arraylist. When clear() runs the listview counter changes to 0 and then the app starts downloading the online data. So i cant use clear() function. I even tried now to update the listview using add() as the data return in post execute but still i have duplicates! The only way to make it work is to use listview.setadapter(baseadapter) which shows the correct data on the listview but like this the listview refreshes and user return back to the top and i do not want that. I want as it scrolls down data to show