# Update a field in a listview - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, field

I have a ListView and a spinner and when I want select from the spinner, I want to update one field for every item in the ListView with the selected value from the spinner.
I have a CustomAdapter which extends CursorAdapter. How can I do that exactly?

Code for CustomCursorAdapterProdus2:

```
public class CustomCursorAdapterProdus2 extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String TAG = null;
Context con;
public CustomCursorAdapterProdus2(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    con = context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View retView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_item_produsefactura, parent, false);
    return retView;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView textViewId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.denumire);
    textViewId.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(1))));
    TextView textId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id_produsFact);
    textId.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(0))));
    TextView textUm = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.unitateMasura);
    textUm.setText(" (" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(cursor.getColumnName(4))) + ")");
    }
}
```

This is the code for single_row_item_produsefactura.xml which fills the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/relativLayoutLista"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:padding="10sp"
          android:background="#4A4A4A">

    <!-- 0 -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/spatiu"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text=""
        />

    <!-- 1 -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/cantitate"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="Cantitate"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spatiu"
        />

    <!-- 2 -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/pret"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="Pret"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/unitateMasura"
        />

    <!-- 3 -->
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/denumire"
        android:background="#2A2A2A"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="(denumire)"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spatiu"
        /> 

    <!-- 4 -->
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_cantitate"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:maxLength="7"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/denumire"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cantitate"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <!-- 5 -->
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/butplus"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:onClick="onClickGoPlus"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_cantitate"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/denumire"
        android:text="+1">
    </Button>

     <!-- 6 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butplus10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:onClick="onClickGoPlus"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/butplus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/denumire"
        android:text="+10">
    </Button>   

    <!-- 7 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butminus"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:onClick="onClickGoPlus"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/butplus10"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/denumire"
        android:text="-1">
    </Button>

    <!-- 8 -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butminus10"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleInset"
        android:layout_width="55dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:onClick="onClickGoPlus"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/butminus"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/denumire"
        android:text="-10">
    </Button>

    <!-- 9 -->
    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edit_pret"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="7"
        android:text="0"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/pret"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/denumire"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/butminus10"
        android:clickable="true"
        />

    <!-- 10 -->
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/id_produsFact"
        android:background="#2A2A2A"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="(id_produsFact)"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spatiu"/>
     <!-- 11 -->
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/valoare"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="Valoare"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pret"
        />
     <!-- 12 -->
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/valoaretva"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="Valoare Tva"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/valoare"
        />
     <!-- 13 -->
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_valoare"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_pret"
        android:layout_below="@+id/valoare"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        />
     <!-- 14 -->
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv_valoaretva"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:maxLength="8"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_valoare"
        android:layout_below="@+id/valoaretva"
        />
     <!--  15 -->
     <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/unitateMasura"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#FCFBFD"
        android:text="()"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cantitate"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can use setAdapter() method after every click. It will reload the whole list.

Comment: You should google before writing here a question. Check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198425/updating-the-list-view-when-the-adapter-data-changes)

Comment: Thank you! I am not a pro in Android, but I hope I will understand.