# How to refresh listview after click imagebutton in listview item from adapter?

Tags: android, listview

please help me.

just want to know how can i refresh listview after i click imagebutton in my item.

here is my button onclick inside adapter..

```
buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (arg0 != null) {
                    FragmentOne_DbAdapter database=new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
                    database.open();


                    if(favorite.matches("0")) {
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id,"1");
                        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                        //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),favorite,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "0");
                        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                        //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),favorite,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

here is my complete adapter..

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v4.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Joe on 6/29/2016.
 */
public class FragmentOne_Adapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public FragmentOne_Adapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView txtArtist = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.artist);
        TextView txtVolume = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.volume);
        TextView txtNumber = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.number);

        final ImageButton buttonHeart = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.heart);


        final int _id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
        String title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("title"));
        String artist = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("artist"));
        String volume = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("volume"));
        final String favorite = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("favorite"));
        String number = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("number"));

        // Populate fields with extracted properties
        txtTitle.setText(title);
        txtArtist.setText(artist);
        txtVolume.setText(volume);
        txtNumber.setText(number);

        if(favorite.matches("0")) {
            buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
        }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
            buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
        }

        buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (arg0 != null) {
                    FragmentOne_DbAdapter database=new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(context);
                    database.open();


                    if(favorite.matches("0")) {
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id,"1");
                        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heartred);
                        //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),favorite,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else if(favorite.matches("1")){
                        database.updateItemFavorite(_id, "0");
                        buttonHeart.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
                        //Toast.makeText(arg0.getContext(),favorite,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one_slview, parent, false);
    }

}
```

and here is my fragment..

```
package com.magicstarme.virtualsongbook;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FilterQueryProvider;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FragmentOne.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FragmentOne#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public FragmentOne() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentOne.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static FragmentOne newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        FragmentOne fragment = new FragmentOne();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    private FragmentOne_DbAdapter dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private FragmentOne_Adapter FragmentOneAdapter;
    ListView listView;
    EditText player1ESearch;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_one, container, false);

        TabHost host = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

        //Tab 1
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("SONG LIST");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        spec.setIndicator("SONG LIST");
        host.addTab(spec);


            player1ESearch = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.player1Search);
            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.slPlayer1ListView);
            dbHelper = new FragmentOne_DbAdapter(getActivity());
            dbHelper.open();
            //Clean all data
            //dbHelper.deleteAllPlayer1();
            //Add some data
            dbHelper.insertPlayer1Songlist();
            //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
            displayPlayer1ListView();

            ImageButton dplayer1ESearch=(ImageButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            dplayer1ESearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        player1ESearch.setText("");
                    }
            });


        //Tab 2
        spec = host.newTabSpec("NEW SONGS");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        spec.setIndicator("NEW SONGS");
        host.addTab(spec);

        //Tab 3
        spec = host.newTabSpec("FAVORITES");
        spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        spec.setIndicator("FAVORITES");
        host.addTab(spec);

        return rootView;
    }

    private void displayPlayer1ListView() {
        Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllPlayer1();

        FragmentOneAdapter = new FragmentOne_Adapter(getActivity(), cursor, 0);
        listView.setAdapter(FragmentOneAdapter);

        player1ESearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                      int before, int count) {
                FragmentOneAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            }
        });

        FragmentOneAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchPlayer1ByTitle(constraint.toString());
            }
        });

    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your adapter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating the list view when the adapter data changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198425/updating-the-list-view-when-the-adapter-data-changes)

Comment: try notifyDataStChanged(); before that update the list.

Comment: maybe its duplicate but i cant find an answer that seminar to my code.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple call `notifyDataSetChanged();` when you click in button for refresh your `ListView`

```
buttonHeart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
         ...
         notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your list view is connected with adapter. You need to notify this adapter to redraw the list view. Can you give more information where exactly your button click listener code is (in which class). If it is inside your adapter class (like I suppose) you can do something like this in your click listener code (some where inside the method public void onClick(View arg0) ) :

```
YourAdapterClassName.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your adapter constructor to accept the Fragment as a parameter.

Something like :

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, int id, HomeFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

then you call methods using the fragment variable.

```
fragment.doSomething();
```

and in this method you can refresh the list using  `notifyDataSetChanged();`