# update the list view when data changes

Tags: android, rest

I am creating Android application for an IOT product .
I am uploading sensor data to an web serves developed in REST architecture.
web service is working perfectly .
I want show in real time that if sensor data changes.
I want retrive data and update the Textview
how can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating the list view when the adapter data changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198425/updating-the-list-view-when-the-adapter-data-changes)

Answer (score 0):

For refreshing listview data,you need to use the following line of code,

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where,

```
    adapter = your listview adapter object
```

Write above line of code after you retrieve data from a server or local database.

Answer (score 0):

You want to update a textview or a listview?
If it is that you want to keep adding new records to a list view, just add the items to the listview adapter as they come in and call youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged() so the listview updates its content.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Code in your adapter list like :

```
Adapter_Constructer(List<String> data){
this.data=data;
notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

and then update it when u want

or just use :

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

in your response method.

or Reinitialize and reset adapter then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`