# In Android how do you get an alert dialog to add an item to a list if the user presses yes and viceversa

Tags: android, android-menu

I am developing a simple Restaurant application in Android, I used menus and inflated submenu items corresponding to each menu item, I wanted to know a way of how to add the name of the dish to list only if the user selects yes in the alert dialog and viceversa.
Here is my code

```
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem m)
    {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(m);
        switch(m.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.Chicken_Biryani:
            selectedItem.add(m.getTitle().toString());
            cost.add(150);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Hyderabadi special: Chicken   biryani costs 150 Rs"+selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG); 
            break;

            case R.id.Butter_Chicken:
            selectedItem.add(m.getTitle().toString());
            cost.add(150);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Now with Punjabi Tadka: Butter Chicken costs 150 Rs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            showDialog(ALERT_DIALOG);   

            break;

                   ........

      public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch(id)
        {
        case ALERT_DIALOG:
        AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ab.setTitle("Buy Items");
        ab.setMessage(" You have added the item to your cart ");
        ab.setIcon(R.drawable.shopcart);
        ab.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){         
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Item added to cart your cart contains "+selectedItem.size()+" Items", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();    
            }});    
    Dialog ad = ab.create();
        return ad;  
        }
        return null;    

        }
```

// how do i pass the data of the onOptionsItemSelected to the list only if the user selects yes in the alertdiaolog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2345875/android-notifydatasetchanged) question for more information. It links to another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426) which talks about how and when you can use [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29).

I think in your AlertDialog you would want an "Add" button and a "Cancel" button to cancel adding it to the cart. Upon clicking add, your would insert the item into the users cart. To add another button to your AlertDialog you would use ab.setNegativeButton(...) just as you did with the setPositiveButton. This is just my take on it, am I correctly understanding your use of onCreateDialog - or is it used only to tell the user it has been added?

Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330536/help-refreshing-list-with-notifydatasetchanged) question for more specific help on how to implement within an AlertDialog.

Comment: yes you are right, I did that but had to change it because I was unable to do so, can you please modify my code and let me know the procedure for doing

Comment: I mean how do I use notifyDataSetChanged method in AlertDialog

Comment: Please see my edits, that question uses the notifyDataSetChanged in an AlertDialog