# android what to use instead of onRestart() in a fragment

Tags: java, android, lifecycle, oncreate

I'm dealing with .setVisibility() of a **view**, inside my main fragment at app start.
So what I want is that the **view** is invisible on app start (for this i set INVISIBLE inside onCreateView) and to be visible when I come back to my fragment from other activities while the app is open (and for this I tried to use onRestart() to set **view** VISIBLE but it cannot resolve onRestart method)
is onRestart deprecated or?
thanks

**EDIT:** for all the answers below suggesting to use an onResume (and whom gave a -1), onResume doesn't work as onRestart at all, cause is being called right after onCreateView.

Comment: hi **m4tt**  i had the same problem, did u get the answer for that?

Comment: its been a while, but from what i recall, the correct answer was the edit of the reply below, since his first answer wasn't on point. still i had a -2 and he got upvoted cause nobody understood the issue. after i made him notice it he posted the boolean thing which i think worked.

Answer (score 19):

Fragments don't have `onRestart()`. It's only for Activities.

See the lifecycle of fragments below

[image]

I suppose you're looking for `onResume()` instead

---

Use a boolean flag to check whether or not you're returning to the Fragment:

```
private boolean firstVisit;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //other stuff
    firstVisit = true;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    //other stuff
    if (firstVisit) {
        //do stuff for first visit only

        firstVisit = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is onResume is being read also on app start right after onCreate()

Comment: @m4tt use a bool to check whether you're in it the 1st time or not (the latter means you are returning to it)

Comment: @TimCastelijns ok, so your +2 answer looks incomplete, my -1 question looks due instead, cause I need more than an onResume to achieve onRestart result

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `onResume()` callback method, if you would like to detect when the fragment is visible again

Comment: onResume doesn't work as onRestart at all, cause is being called right after onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

Fragment life cycle doesn't have `onRestart()` method. You could use `onPause()` and `onResume()` as per your requirement.

Further reading : [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: onResume doesn't work as onRestart at all, cause is being called right after onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `onStart()` or `onResume()` if you want to load things when returning to the fragment.

Comment: Sadly fragments don't have onrestart

Comment: onResume doesn't work as onRestart at all, cause is being called right after onCreateView

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onRestart()` on the activity, making it call whatever method you want on the fragment by making use of `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.your_fragment)`.
When a fragment gets restarted its underlying activity got restarted so its `onRestart()` method was called.