# Admob Interstitial Preloading

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, interstitial

I'm implementing Admob interstitial ads in a button. But it take 3-4 seconds to load the ads, user wrongly click button again and app get crush. How to preload interstitial ads or load instantly when press the button. Here is my code.

```js
img_ply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitial.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.admob_intertestial_id));
    mInterstitial.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
     @Override
     public void onAdLoaded() {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onAdLoaded();
      if (mInterstitial.isLoaded()) {
       mInterstitial.show();
       mInterstitial.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
         super.onAdClosed();
         finish();

         Intent inttv = new Intent(SingleChannelActivity.this, TvPlay.class);
         inttv.putExtra("url", ChannelUrl);
         startActivity(inttv);
        }
       });
      }else{
       super.onAdLoaded();


      }
     }
    });
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put Interstitial load method into onCreate() function of view, not in onClick event of the button !
So, there will be only mInterstitial.show() method in onClick() event.
You must load the inters ads onCreate() and inters ads will be ready whenever you need..

Comment: Appear interstitial ads, proceed to new activity and after clicked Back Button, I cannot click  the ads implemented button again... any suggestion?

Comment: You must implement onResume() method at first activity, and put code inters.load and set event listener there also.. you can look here more solutions.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545217/back-button-and-refreshing-previous-activity