# update RecyclerView from another activity onBackpressed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I have a `recyclerView` on first Activity(reads data from DB) and insert data on it from second activity(Insert data into DB).
Now I want to update that `recyclerView`  when Back `buttonPressed` on second Activity(when back from second activity to first activity)
now what should I do?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: First try to do some search before asking question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545217/back-button-and-refreshing-previous-activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to update RecyclerView Adapter Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367599/how-to-update-recyclerview-adapter-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LiveData and Room. Whenever room database updates, it'll give trigger onChanged to LiveData. Hence, If your activity is observing the room database. You can simply call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` inside the observer.