# Replace all entries in list adapter

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter

Can someone explain me why the following code does not work? 
I am trying to update my list of Report everytime the user clicks the refresh button with the following code

In `updateReports` (after all the download of data and the parsing):

```
reportsList = newReportsList;
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Previously in `onCreateView`:

```
listAdapter = new ReportsListAdapter(activity, R.layout.list_item_reports, reportsList);
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

But the list does not refresh and keeps showing the old reports. I tried with `listAdapter.clear()` and `listAdapter.add()` with a `for` (I can not use `addAll` because I need to work with API 10) but it gave me a null pointer exception.

Any strategies to do this replacement in the cleanest way possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
reportsList = newReportsList;
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Does not work because you are just updating the reference `reportsList` holds with a reference to `newReportsList`. This does not update the reference the adaptor has (the original reference to the original array)

Your second approach should work, but you'd need to post the class code and give detail of the `NullPointerException`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! Do you think that second approach is the right way to go? It seems to me a bit dirty :/

Comment: The alternative would be to create a new `ReportsListAdapter`, but you already have one. In this case I'd say clearing the list and adding new object data is the correct approach. As you mention, from API 11 you could have used `addAll(...)`, which would have tidied it up a bit. I assume you can't just add/remove/update based on differences between the current and new data.

Comment: Thanks. I am going to leave the question open for a couple of days to see if anyone else comes with a different opinion, ok? :)

Answer (score 1):

First check if your method updateReports is really called after download.
Second check if your reportsList did really change contents, you can simply log values of it before and after assigning with newReportsList.

Comment: I already tried that, thanks. The method is called and the values are changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
reportsList.clear();
reportsList.addAll(newReportsList);
listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

This should work

Answer (score 0):

It is not the solution that I wanted, but until I find an explanation for my problem I will reset the adapter:

```
reportsList = newReportsList;
listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

More info and approaches here:
[Android List view refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088862/android-list-view-refresh/4088889#comment8239756_4088889)