# Android OnResume hangs activity

Tags: android

i am making an sms app ,the problem is that when new sms received activity don't refresh listview ,i tried notiy datasetchanged but nothing happend.
I placed code onresume method
but i hangs my app when new sms receive.when i put code into asynctask it gives error.

```
void update() {
    getAll.clear();
    Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, "date DESC");

    startManagingCursor(c);
    count = new String[c.getCount()];
    snippet = new String[c.getCount()];
    thread_id = new String[c.getCount()];

    String[] num=new String[c.getCount()];
    date=new String[c.getCount()];
    address=new String[c.getCount()];
    c.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount()-1; i++) {
        count[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("message_count"))
                        .toString();

        thread_id[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"))
                        .toString();
        snippet[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
        date[i]=c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));   
        Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, "thread_id = " + thread_id[i], null, null);
        cur.moveToFirst();
        startManagingCursor(cur);
        num[i] = getContactName(this,cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
        address[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
        getAll.add(count[i]+","+num[i]+","+snippet[i]);
        Log.d("help",num[i]);

        c.moveToNext();           
    }

    adapter = new HomeAdapter(this, R.layout.sms, getAll,date);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    list.setAdapter(adapter);  
}
```

2.In OnResume

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `mMyListView.invalidate();` or `mMyListView.invalidateViews();`

If that doesnt work, refer to this

`((BaseAdapter) mMyListView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();`

Read the refresh ListView  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088862/android-list-view-refresh/4088889#4088889) .

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a thread, something like this should work:
However, others are saying that there are better ways of doing this so you could look at their links and see if their way is better...

```
void update() {

    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            getAll.clear();
            Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, null, null, "date DESC");

            startManagingCursor(c);
            count = new String[c.getCount()];
            snippet = new String[c.getCount()];
            thread_id = new String[c.getCount()];

            String[] num = new String[c.getCount()];
            date = new String[c.getCount()];
            address = new String[c.getCount()];
            c.moveToFirst();

            for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount() - 1; i++) {
                if (i ==35){
                    i = 35;
                }
                count[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("message_count")).toString();

                thread_id[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")).toString();
                snippet[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("snippet"));
                date[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date"));
                Cursor cur = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), null, "thread_id = " + thread_id[i], null, null);
                cur.moveToFirst();
                startManagingCursor(cur);
                try {
                    num[i] = getContactName(Home.this, cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    address[i] = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                getAll.add(count[i] + "," + num[i] + "," + snippet[i]);
                //Log.d("help", num[i]);

                c.moveToNext();

            }

            Home.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter = new HomeAdapter(Home.this, R.layout.sms, getAll, date);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }
    };
    thread.start();

}
```